# Collapsible-header with a checkbox in MaterializeCSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I need to make a collapsible with checkbox in the header (in MaterializeCSS)

I needed that everytime I click on the checkbox as checked, the corresponding collapsible section will expand (consquently, when unchecked, the section will collapse)

or you can think of it as:

Everytime I expand the collapsible-header, the checkbox will be checked and the section will expand (and when I collapse the header, the checkbox will be unchecked and the section will collapse)

I'm very new to Javascript and Materialize and I'm pretty sure there's a better implementation since my implementation poses a problem:

My implementation does not update the checkbox when I click outside the bounds of the checkbox label but still within the bounds of the collapsible-header div. Instead, it just collapses/expands. It's pretty understandable why that happpens but I can't think of a work around and hoping to get some ideas here.

For my trial code below, I am forcing it to work on the first section only:

My HTML code is:

```
<ul class="collapsible">
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">
      <input id = "isChecked" type = "checkbox" checked = "checked" />
      First
      </div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Second</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="collapsible-header">Third</div>
      <div class="collapsible-body"><span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Consequently, my javascript code is:

```
 if (document.getElementById('isChecked').checked)
    {
        $(".one").addClass("active");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".one").removeClass("active");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I made radio buttons so that we can select either one option out of multiple options. 
With the help of `let eles = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");` you can get all the radio input field.

Attached `click` event to all those radio buttons

```
for (let i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
  eles[i].addEventListener('click', openColl);
}
```

Then checking if the radio button is checked then we can open that collapsible

```
openColl = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
    if (eles[i].checked) {
      console.log(eles[i].value);
      inst.open(eles[i].value);
    }
  }
};
```

To open up the particular collapsible section, we are using `instance.open(1);`. You can find this in the documentation of materialize.

**HTML**

```
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" value="0" />
    <span>First</span>
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" value="1" />
    <span>Second</span>
  </label>
</p>
<p>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" value="2" />
    <span>Third</span>
  </label>
</p>

<ul class="collapsible">
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">
      <i class="material-icons">filter_drama</i>First
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">
      <i class="material-icons">place</i>Second
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="collapsible-header">
      <i class="material-icons">whatshot</i>Third
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    let coll = document.querySelector('.collapsible');
    M.Collapsible.init(coll);
    let inst = M.Collapsible.getInstance(coll);
    let eles = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']");
    openColl = () => {
      for (let i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
        if (eles[i].checked) {
          console.log(eles[i].value);
          inst.open(eles[i].value);
        }
      }
    };
    for (let i = 0; i < eles.length; i++) {
      eles[i].addEventListener('click', openColl);
    }
})
```